# React Stateless function HOC get inner elment as ref

Tags: reactjs

According to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> **You may not use the ref attribute on functional components** because they don't have instances.

However, what would happen if my functional component is a HOC?, and I want to get the ref to the inner component, which will not be stateless.

I have the following Component:

```
export default (WrappedComponent) => {
  let meta = {};
  const WithForm = (props, context) => {
    const newMeta = { form: context.form };
    if (!shallowEqual(meta, newMeta)) {
      meta = newMeta;
    }
    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...props}
        meta={meta}
      />
    );
  };
  WithForm.propTypes = {
    meta: PropTypes.object
  };
  WithForm.contextTypes = {
    form: PropTypes.object
  };
  return WithForm;
};
```

I would love to bypass this stateless component, to it's parent, doing something like:

```
<WrappedComponent
  {...props}
  meta={meta}
  ref={this.ref} /* obviously wont work */
/>
```

i.e.:

```
ComponentB: WithForm(B);

Component A:

  render() {
    return <ComponentB ref={(instance) => { this.b = instance }} />
  }
```

Is there any way to reach a similar solution?

**NOTE:**

- Please, I already thought about creating my own function and call it with **this** instance --> this.props.attachMyRef(this);
- I also thought about making this stateless component to be normal react component.

Do not post this kind of answers, I would like to really make use of the ref attribute, unless there is not really a solution for the issue